# Cómo puedo resumir una lista o arreglo de elementos con subtotales en Flutter?

Tags: bucle-for, flutter, map, ordenamiento

Tengo una clase llamada Alimento con dos componentes: el nombre (**idAlimento** de tipo String) y la cantidad (**cantidad** de tipo double). Igualmente, tengo una larga lista de alimentos así:

```
class Alimento {
  final String idAlimento;
  final double cantidad;

  Alimento(this.idAlimento, this.cantidad);
}

List<Alimento> data = [
  new Alimento("Banano", 11),
  new Alimento("Banano", 22),
  new Alimento("Durazno", 33),
  new Alimento("Manzana", 44),
  new Alimento("Banano", 55),
  new Alimento("Durazno", 66),
];
```

Quiero resumirlos de tal forma que tenga un solo idAlimento para cada uno con el total de cantidades, así:

```
Banano        88
Manzana       44
Durazno       99
```

La forma que encontré para hacerlo fue primero ordenar la Lista por idAlimento (nombre) y después hacer un bucle for con muchas comparaciones, sin embargo no crea que sea el código más óptimo. Entiendo que flutter tiene algunas funciones como .map y .reduce que podrían hacer todo más fácil pero no sé cómo usarlas en este caso. Alguien tiene una mejor forma para lograr el objetivo?:

```
data.sort((a, b) => a.idAlimento.compareTo(b.idAlimento)); //Para ordenar la lista de Alimento

List<Alimento> _salidaAlim = []; //esta variable es la que va a almacenar la nueva lista resumida
Alimento _anterior = data[0];

for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  if(data[i].idAlimento == _anterior.idAlimento) {
    _anterior.cantidad += data[i].cantidad;
    if (i==data.length-1) {_salidaAlim.add(_anterior);} 
  } else {
    _salidaAlim.add(_anterior);
    _anterior = data[i];
    if (i==data.length-1) {_salidaAlim.add(data[i]);} 
  }
}
```

Comment: Puedes actualizar tu pregunta poniendo data Dummy para poder probarlo aquí y mejorar la lógica?

Comment: Gracias Roger, la data Dummy es la que está en el cuerpo de la pregunta (Banano, Manzana, etc con sus valores). No se si a esto te refieres o tu pregunta es diferente. Sería algo como: Alimento[0].idAlimento = "Banano"; Alimento[0].cantidad = 11; Alimento[1].idAlimento = "Banano", etc

Comment: Digo que agregues directamente el código de la clase Alimento, y código agregando datos a tu array para correr y probar desde aquí

Comment: por cierto quien es Roger?

Comment: Jajaja, lo siento, me aparecía Roger en algún lado de la página. Soy nuevo en StackOverflow. Te agradezco mucho @diegoveloper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con un `Map` de ayuda simplemente, aquí preparé ejemplo:

```dart
    Map<String, double> sumMap = {};
    for (Alimento alimento in data) {
      sumMap[alimento.idAlimento] = (sumMap[alimento.idAlimento] ?? 0.0) + alimento.cantidad;
    }
    // Datos en Map
    print(sumMap);
    // Datos en List
    final listUpdated = sumMap.keys.map((e) => Alimento(e, sumMap[e])).toList();
    listUpdated.sort((a, b) => a.idAlimento.compareTo(b.idAlimento));
    print(listUpdated);
```

El código sin print ni comentario se reduce a lo siguiente:

```dart
    Map<String, double> sumMap = {};
    for (Alimento alimento in data) {
      sumMap[alimento.idAlimento] = (sumMap[alimento.idAlimento] ?? 0.0) + alimento.cantidad;
    }
    final _salidaAlim = sumMap.keys.map((e) => Alimento(e, sumMap[e])).toList();
    _salidaAlim.sort((a, b) => a.idAlimento.compareTo(b.idAlimento));
```

Ya puedes usar `_salidaAlim` que son los datos actualizados, si lo quieres tener global, sacas la variable fuera del método.

**UPDATE**

Si no deseas usar Map, aquí tienes otra opción con solo listas.
NOTA: tienes que sobreescribir el operador `=` y el getter `hashCode` .

```dart
class Alimento {
  final String idAlimento;
  final double cantidad;
  Alimento(this.idAlimento, this.cantidad);
  String toString() => "$idAlimento vs $cantidad";
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) || other is Alimento && runtimeType == other.runtimeType && idAlimento == other.idAlimento;
  @override
  int get hashCode => idAlimento.hashCode;
}
```

y luego

```dart
    List<Alimento> _salidaAlim = [];
    data.sort((a, b) => a.idAlimento.compareTo(b.idAlimento));
    for (Alimento alimento in data) {
      if (!_salidaAlim.contains(alimento)) {
        _salidaAlim.add(Alimento(
            alimento.idAlimento,
            data
                .where((e) => e.idAlimento == alimento.idAlimento)
                .fold<double>(0.0, (previousValue, e) => previousValue + e.cantidad)));
      }
    }
    print(_salidaAlim);
```

Comment: Hola Diego, está interesante tu enfoque, sin embargo me gustaría hacer algo que no requiera pasar la clase a un mapa, dado que dicha clase tiene una cantidad de elementos más como descripción, propiedades del alimento, etc. Quisiera encontrar una forma que se pueda hacer con Listas.

Comment: ahí puse mi respuesta actualizada

Comment: Muchas gracias @diegoveloper. Esa combinación de .fold y .where funciona bien para encontrar los alimentos y sumar el total!!!

Comment: dale, no te olvides de marcar la pregunta como solucionada :)